# Issue with loop devices in Docker

Tags: docker, loop-device

I'm trying to build a virtual disk image in Docker.
I'm able to create my empty file with `dd` and create the partitions with `parted` but once I try to make my filesystem it fails saying the device could not be found. In the Docker container I'm running as `root` and I've passed `--privileged=true` to `docker run`.

This works outside of docker and works in Docker on my local machine. It's only failing on my build server (AWS elastic agent).

Here is a section of the output showing that the block device exist before the call to make the filesystem.

```
28-Feb-2019 10:39:33  +./scripts/make.sh:105> ls -l /dev/loop2 /dev/loop2p1 /dev/loop2p2
28-Feb-2019 10:39:33  brwxrwxrwx 1 root disk   7, 2 Feb 28 15:39 /dev/loop2
28-Feb-2019 10:39:33  brwxrwxrwx 1 root disk 259, 8 Feb 28 15:39 /dev/loop2p1
28-Feb-2019 10:39:33  brwxrwxrwx 1 root disk 259, 9 Feb 28 15:39 /dev/loop2p2
28-Feb-2019 10:39:33  +./scripts/make.sh:108> mkfs.vfat -n boot /dev/loop2p1
28-Feb-2019 10:39:33  mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
28-Feb-2019 10:39:33  /dev/loop2p1: No such device or address
```

And the section of the script:

```
## Create zero'd file
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1M count=400

## Find next available loop device
local lodev=$(losetup -f)

## Have flat file look like a block device
ls -l ${lodev}*
losetup ${lodev} disk.img

## Create partition table and partition
parted -s -a optimal ${lodev} mklabel msdos
parted -s -a optimal -- ${lodev} unit compact mkpart primary "10" "20"
parted -s -a optimal -- ${lodev} unit compact mkpart primary "21" "-1"
parted -s ${lodev} set 1 boot on
ls -l ${lodev}*

## Create filesystem
mkfs.vfat -n boot ${lodev}p1
mkfs.ext3 -L rootfs ${lodev}p2
```

Any ideas why `mkfs.fat` thinks the block device does not exist when it looks like it does?

Comment: You don't need --privileged you can use --device mapping. See https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/

Comment: This would require the devices to be created and setup before entering the container, which is half of what this script does when creating the virtual image.